# Chaining Linear Map affecting a Hessian Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, hessian-matrix

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable and $L: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be linear described by the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$. Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \ g(x,y) = f(L(x,y))$.

What relation do $H_f(0)$ and $H_g(0)$ share? (These $H$'s are Hessian matrices.)

By mere calculation, I can't seem to find any algebraic relationship. Perhaps, it is asked about size properties or linear algebra properties?

Comment: the $H_g(0)$ is a linear combination of $H_f(0)$ maybe? trying to compute derivatives and using the chain rule should derive sth like this

Comment: Are you sure? I can only get ugly results, though possibly I just miscalculated.

Comment: It turns out that $H_g(0) = A^T H_f(0) A$.